# Warning: ldap_mod_replace(): Modify: Object class violation

Tags: php, ldap

I've an issue when I try to edit something (in this case the [mail] field) in my ldap. Error: Warning: ldap_mod_replace(): Modify: Object class violation

here my code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(30);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

// config
$ldapserver = '10.32.32.100';
$ldapport = '60389';
$ldapuser      = 'uid=pablo.ghisolfi,ou=staff,ou=people,ou=data,DC=something-education,DC=com'; 
$ldappass     = '1234.abcd';
$ldaptree    = "dc=something-education,dc=com";

// connect
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver,$ldapport) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if($ldapconn) {
    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or die ("Error trying to bind: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...<br /><br />";


        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldaptree, "(employeeNumber=1234567890)") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldapconn));
        $data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

        // iterate over array and print data for each entry
        echo '<h1>Show me the users</h1>';
        for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++) {
            //echo "dn is: ". $data[$i]["dn"] ."<br />";
            echo "cn: ". $data[$i]["cn"][0] ."<br />";
            if(isset($data[$i]["sn"][0])) {
                echo "sn: ". $data[$i]["sn"][0] ."<br />";
            } else {
                echo "sn: None<br /><br />";
            }

            if(isset($data[$i]["description"][0])) {
                echo "description: ". $data[$i]["description"][0] ."<br /><br />";
            } else {
                echo "description: None<br /><br />";
            }
        }
        // print number of entries found
        echo "Number of entries found: " . ldap_count_entries($ldapconn, $result);
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}


$entry[mail] = "pablo.ghisolfi@something.comqqqqqqqqq";
  $results = ldap_mod_replace($ldapconn, "ou=staff, ou=people, ou=data, dc=something-education, dc=com", $entry);


// all done? clean up
ldap_close($ldapconn);
?>
```

It binds to ldap: LDAP bind successful...
It shows the searched user: cn, sn, description
It shows the warning at the end: Warning: ldap_mod_replace(): Modify: Object class violation

I thank very much if someone can help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify the mail attribute on the "ou=staff" entry which is an OrganizationalUnit. Such objectClass doesn't allow a "mail" attribute. So trying to add it is a violation of the schema and more specifically of the object class attributes,

Comment: Hi Ludovic, I tried to change something in my attribute ou, but nothing changes, so what do you suggest to modify in my code? Thanks for you help

Comment: Try to do the modification to the user (DN) and not to the parent entry.